# retain contentView and release NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

```
_mainView = [[_window contentView] retain]; 
...
[_window release];
_window = nil;
return _mainView;
```

I meet code snippet above, I want to know what effects it really makes.
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Now you are the owner of highest accessible `NSView` object in the window’s view hierarchy.

```
NSView  *mainView = [[window1 contentView] retain]; 
[window1 release];
window1 = nil;
[window setContentView:mainView];
```